# Formatting echo output in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a hack script that is checking for some entries in a vary large log file.
It is a mix of perl and bash - it works fine  - the script gets what it needs to
get.  The only problem is the formatting "$chdk_subscription" I have tried to delimit the output by a keyword
'STATS' and 'added'. These two words are at the beginning and the end of each line that
I want to read.

```
#!/bin/bash
pid_foo_process=$(pgrep foo_process)
check_primary=$(grep $1 /data/foo_process-0210.$pid_foo_process.log | perl -nle 'print /(primary book \w+:\w+)/ ')
check_primary_symbol=$(grep $1 /data/foo_process-0210.$pid_foo_process.log | perl -nle 'print /primary book (\w+:\w+)/ ')
chdk_subscription=$(grep $1 /data/foo_process-0210.$pid_foo_process.log | perl -nle 'print if /(subscription for \w+:\w+.*)/ ')
echo $check_primary
echo $check_primary_symbol

IFS="STAT"
while read line
echo $line
done < echo $chdk_subscription
```

Breaking up "$chdk_subscription"  by 'IFS' does not seem to work

```
echo $chdk_subscription| awk -F"STATS" '{print $0}'
```

using awk is not working either -- each time it comes out as one big line with no newlines.

```
STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391048 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:T added STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391164 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:P added STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391226 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:Z added STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391537 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:n added STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391599 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:A added STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391686 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:a added STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391756 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:K added STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391818 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:J added STATS 10/15 09:38:12.826928 32978 (0)SB: subscription for APA:N, XNYSAPA:3 added
```

I want something like this that I can read.

```
STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391048 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:T added
STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391164 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:P added
STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391226 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:Z added
STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391537 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:n added
STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391599 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:A added
STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391686 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:a added
STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391756 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:K added
STATS 10/15 08:03:09.391818 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:J added
STATS 10/15 09:38:12.826928 32978  (0)SB: subscription for APA:N, XNYSAPA:3 added
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how it looks BEFORE the filtering, which corresponds to the expected output you already presented.

Comment: I don't grok the details of what you're trying to do, but one important note: Quote! `echo $line` **IS NOT THE SAME AS** `echo "$line"`; the former will change newlines to spaces, expand glob expressions, and do all kinds of other messing with your formatting you almost certainly don't want.

Comment: Also, unless you want backslash-escape sequences parsed (for instance, `\n` changed from two characters into a single newline), use `read -r`, not bare `read`.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using a temporary file rather than reading multiple lines into a bash variable.

```
temp_file=$(mktemp)

if [ 0 -eq $? ]; then
  trap 'rm -f -- "${temp_file}"' 0
else
  echo "Unable to create temporary file!"
  exit 1
fi

# Fill temporary file.
pid_foo_process=$(pgrep foo_process)
grep $1 /data/foo_process-0210.${pid_foo_process}.log | perl -nle 'print /(primary book \w+:\w+)/ ' >>"${temp_file}"
grep $1 /data/foo_process-0210.${pid_foo_process}.log | perl -nle 'print /primary book (\w+:\w+)/ ') >>"${temp_file}"
grep $1 /data/foo_process-0210.${pid_foo_process}.log | perl -nle 'print if /(subscription for \w+:\w+.*)/ ' >>"${temp_file}"

# Print contents.
while read line
  echo "${line}"
done < "${temp_file}"
```

Note that the [trap](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) statement at the top will automatically delete the temporary file when the script is finished.

Comment: Significantly improved. I'd suggest using `read -r`, absent a specific and compelling reason to do otherwise. Also, unless you clear `IFS` during the `read` operation, trailing whitespace will be stripped.

Comment: ...and if you want to be able to reliably print lines that only contain, say, `-n` or `-E`, then you're better off using `printf '%s\n' "$line"` rather than `echo` at all.

Comment: I'd also suggest putting `trap 'rm -f -- "$temp_file"' 0` up at the top, instead of having a `rm` at the end; that way if the script exits from some different point rather than running through to the end, the temporary file still gets deleted.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - The formatting of the while loop reflects the code in the question, however your point about the trap is a good one so I'll add that to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=" ?STATS "} NR > 1 {print "STATS "$0}'
```

RS=" ?STATS " is the separator, catching any STATS with a space after him and zero to one spaces before him. This separator will result in a first empty record.
NR is the Record Number, so NR > 1 will ignore the first record.